# this.form.submit() pass the value to the url

Tags: forms, methods, get, action

I have this script.

```
<form method="get">
  <select name="report" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option value="data1">data1</option>
    <option value="data2">data2</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

I want to pass the value of the selected and add the value to the current url(see url below).

```
test.php?link=partners&projectid=value&clientid=value
```

something like this ;

```
 test.php?link=partners&projectid=value&clientid=value&type=data1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `form` like this:

```
<form method="get" action="test.php">
  <select name="report" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option value="data1">data1</option>
    <option value="data2">data2</option>
  </select>
  <input type="hidden" name="link" value="partners">
  <input type="hidden" name="projectid" value="value">
  <input type="hidden" name="clientid" value="value">
</form>
```

You have to use `hidden` type input form fields.

Note: you may have to change the `name` of `select` tag from *report* to *type* as mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 1):

The parameters in the URL are constructed from the form fields only. So, as per your requirement you can add `hidden` fields for `projectId` and `clientId` in addition to your code, add server side code to set the values for this field if it is dynamically retrieved, 
thats it the rest will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to create a javascript function to handle this, something close to the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function somefunction() {
        var xmlhttp;
        var data1 = document.forms.frm1.report.value;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else { // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                // do something
            }
        };

        xmlhttp.open('GET', 'test.php?link=partners&projectid=value&clientid=value&type=' + data1, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }       
</script>
```

Then change your select to the following:

```
<select name="report" onchange="somefunction()">
```

It would be best to put the other values in a hidden field.